# Regex - Capturing a number if a match exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm looking to capture just the number after `vspace`. How would you do that in regex? Here is a sample string.

```
<img align="left" alt="dude its me" border="10" height="168" hspace="30"  vspace="10" width="130" />
```

So the end result would be `10`

Comment: OT: Funny you provided so many attributes, but you didn't mention `src`. : )

Comment: No src's were hurt in the making of this example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> s = '<img align="left" alt="dude its me" border="10" height="168" hspace="30"  vspace="10" width="130" />'
>> /vspace="(\d+)"/.match(s)[1]
=> "10"
```

or, if you're not sure if it exists or not:

```
if /vspace="(\d+)"/ =~ s
  puts $1
else
  puts "no match"
end
```

Comment: It's probably more readable to use s.match(/.../) which follows the Ruby convention than /.../ =~ s which is inherited from Perl and looks a lot more like line-noise to those not familiar with what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind that the vspace could be specified with single quotes, double quotes or no quotes.

```
n = Nokogiri::HTML(%Q{<img align="left" alt="dude its me" border="10" height="168" hspace="30"  vspace="10" width="130" />})
n.css("img").first["vspace"]
```

[Never ever parse HTML with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

To capture just the `10` try this one: `(?=\bvspace=")?(\d+)`

`/vspace="(\d+)"` should match the entirety of `vspace="10"`

Answer (score 0):

```
/vspace="(\d+)"/$1/
```

Comment: Hmm. that last piece with the $1. Not sure I understand that.

Comment: $1 content what is between parenthesis i.e. 10 with your example. I don't know RoR regex but i presume there is something similar.